# Which PHP version is currently running 5.2.15 or 5.3.4?

Tags: php, version

i often read [official PHP website](http://php.net) website.

1. on 9 Dec,2010 headlines was   PHP 5.2.15 Released! **and**
2. on 10 Dec,2010 headlines was  PHP 5.3.4 Released!

i m really confused that what means of two different headlines??
i think version order are may b wrong or what is this??please explain PHP GURU

please tell me what should i said when interviewer ask which version of php we works currently??

**ONE MORE THING**

so which version we need to use for safeside, is that 5.3.x or 5.2.x???

Comment: Similar to Windows XP (still support? don't know) and Windows 7. Or Mac OS X 10.5 and Mac OS X 10.6. Or Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10. Or Python 2.7 and Python 3.1....

Comment: Well, if you can't even figure out which version you are running, you shouldn't be using it in the first place. The obvious thing would be to run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Also -1 for a variety of stylistic reasons.

Comment: What do you mean with *which version we need to use for safeside*? What is *safeside*?

Comment: @Flexi i know that way of using `phpinfo` safeside means a proper satisfactory answer..sorry for bad english

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 5.2 and 5.3 series are both maintained in parallel, since 5.3 introduces some fairly big changes and might break older scripts.  The older version will therefore be maintained with security patches and bug fixes for some time to allow people time to migrate their scripts to the new version.

Comment: couldn't say it faster myself.

Comment: so according to you, which version we have to use, (plz dont say to check the XAMPP)???

Comment: @diEcho: For new development, I would use the 5.3 series.

Answer (score 1):

These are minor versions, some people need some  bug fixed but don't want to step to another major version.

Comment: 5.2 and 5.3 are both the same major version.  I think you meant they don't want to step to a different minor version?

Comment: @cdhowie: I think you have to read it like this: `5.2.15` and `5.3.4` are minor versions and `5.2.15` is released too because not everyone upgraded to `5.3` (and therefore gets `5.3.4`) :)

Comment: @Felix: Version numbers go major.minor.release -- so the step from 5.2 to 5.3 is not stepping between major releases.  I'm just nitpicking terminology.

Comment: @cdhowie. I think a better term would be "branches". And then .15 and .4 are really just minor revisions to two different variants. (While I'd like to avoid glorifiung PHP revisions as different languages [ala "PHP4 is bad, PHP5 is teh new!!!1!" meme].)

Answer (score 0):

I would also be a bit careful about claiming a different version of PHP than what you actually know how to use. if you say you're using PHP 5.3 the next question very well may be (What functions have been deprecated in 5.3?)

Answer (score 0):

That's listing the latest versions of two working branches - 5.2 and 5.3. 5.2 is older, but presumably 5.3 has changes that make it incompatible with existing software, so they're still bugfixing 5.3

But it sounds like your question is specific to the place you're trying to get a job, in which case they could be using any version of PHP. `php -version` ought to tell you - my webserver prints

```
PHP 5.2.14 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2010 16:17:01)  
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group  
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies  
    with Zend Extension Manager v1.2.2, Copyright (c) 2003-2007, by Zend Technologies
    with Zend Optimizer v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2009, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: . you suggested method is good and i know too, but what shoud i say wen asked which version is released??

Comment: @diEcho: Say 5.2 and 5.3 and be prepared to tell them the biggest differences between those.

Comment: You explain how there's a older release that's still maintained, but there's a newer release (5.3). Take a look at the php.net homepage again, and look at the right-hand side. But without meaning to sound condescending, you shouldn't be claiming to know much about the development history of PHP, especially in a job interview, because you don't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 5.3. 5.2 in "security fixes only" maintenance mode and the recent release is probably the last one for 5.2 series. That means unless there's an outrageous gaping security hole discovered there will be no releases on 5.2 anymore and no bugfixes or improvements. 5.3 is the current maintained version of PHP. It is better than 5.2 in any respect, use it please :)

5.2 is maintained because some people are slow or reluctant to move to more recent version ("if it works, don't touch it"). However, the answer to the question "what is the current PHP version" is "5.3.4" (at least for today). 5.3 will probably the current version for at least couple of years, then it'd be either 5.4 or maybe 6.

Oh, and the last but not least - all 5.2.x versions are binary and code compatible (i.e. you should not expect any issues upgrading), so are 5.3.x, but between 5.2 and 5.3 there are binary incompatibilities and may be source incompatibilities too, see [upgrading guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php).